imu_filter_madgwick how to use?
I have a simple question about the usage of the filters included in imu_tools.
So far I have succeeded sending my IMU data to rviz from a bag of a D435i RealSense camera, using :
roslaunch realsense2_camera opensource_tracking.launch offline:=true

In Image, selecting /camera/color/image_raw I'm able to see correctly the video registration of the camera.
Despite this, when i look at the rviz simulation, the orientation movements looks good but the frame doesn't move at all, while the camera actually does.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I use imu_filter_madgwick to get a more proper visualization of the movements done by my camera?

I already have installed imu_filter_madgwick package, but I don't know how to use it.
